# Unable to exclude URI from htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect social media crawlers to another file to serve OG data, but I want to exclude rest api calls. All rest api calls use this uri: /api/v1. So one url could look like this: http://www.example.com/api/v1/work. I'm using a CMS (Craft) to serve data.

My htaccess file currently has this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*
RewriteRule ^ sharedata.php [L]
```

But if I go to http://www.example.com/api/v1/work I still get redirected to sharedata.php. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: It's in the webroot.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with these entries, on Apache 2.4:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /sharedata.php [L]
```

(supposing sharedata.php is placed in the root directory)

Comment: Hmm, the ```^.*$``` before the /sharedata.php gives me an internal server error..

Comment: Have you tried to add double quotes around ? ie. RewriteRule "^.*$" /sharedata.php [L]  (the same can apply to RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/api/.*$")

Comment: Do you know the Apache version you are using ? And do you have access to its configuration files ?